# understanding jquery source code - jquery.fn.init

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking into how jQuery source code works, I understand the jQuery object just forwards a call to `jQuery.fn.init` where `jQuery.fn` is just a reference to `jQuery.prototype`.

Then in the source code, there is this line:

```
// Give the init function the jQuery prototype for later instantiation
jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;
```

There is a comment to explain what the code does but I still can't understand it.

1. Can someone explain what does this line of code means? what later instantiation is it talking about and why do we need to set init's prototype to jquery's prototpe?
2. is there a reason (like avoiding conflicts or readability or whatever) that jQuery source code is using jQuery.fn instead of using jQuery.prototype directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This response is written assuming you have some understanding of prototypal inheritance. If you don't, you need to read an article about it to fully understand what's going on. Try doing a Google search for "prototypal inheritance javascript".)

When a new jQuery object is created internally, it is created with `new jQuery.fn.init()`. `init` is a constructor, so setting the `prototype` property on this constructor allows newly created jQuery objects to inherit all the properties of this prototype (all the methods of `jQuery.fn`).

If just `new jQuery()` was used, as you seem to suggest, the object would inherit from `jQuery.prototype` **but** the `jQuery` function would be executed, which as you know does *a lot*. The `init` constructor is used instead because it doesn't come with the baggage of the `jQuery` function. Setting `jQuery.prototype` to the same as `jQuery.fn.init.prototype` just allows you to do `jqueryobject instanceof jQuery`, which is nice, so that's the reason the `jQuery` object has a prototype.

Comment: Only functions have a `prototype` property. All objects have an internal `[[Prototype]]`, but that's a different thing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say the `jQuery` function does *a lot*.  The `jQuery` function simply calls `jQuery.fn.init`, one line.

Setting `jQuery.fn.init.prototype` to `jQuery.fn` isn't just so you can do an `instanceof`.  Because `jQuery()` calls `new jQuery.fn.init()`, the `init` constructor needs a prototype, and preferably one with all the jQuery methods.  All the jQuery methods are on the `jQuery.fn` object, and so these are added to the `init` prototype.  This step also allows the `instanceof` check.

This may have been different at the time of writing - just wanted to clarify

Comment: @NathanWall
Hi, im looking for the snippet where `jQuery(html, attributes)` is defined in the source code. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2
In your answer you mentioned "all the methods of `jQuery.fn`" .. it's got to have a ton of overloads for the `jQuery()` function, can you maybie point me at a GitHub file where i can find these overloads?